# Compactness of the set of convex functions

Tags: functional-analysis

A continuous functions f(x), x∈[a,b] is called convex if for any $x_1,x_2∈[a,b]$, and for any λ∈[0,1]. $f((1−λ)x_1+λx_2)≤(1−λ)f(x_1)+λf(x_2).$

Let $Mϵ⊂C[0,1]$ be the set of functions such that if $f∈Mϵ$then there exists a function g∈C[−ϵ,1+ϵ] Such that: (1) |g(x)|≤1 in C[−ϵ,1+ϵ]; (2) g(x) is convex on C[−ϵ,1+ϵ]; and (3) g(x)=f(x) for any x∈[0,1].

Prove that $Mϵ$ is compact for any ϵ>0.

I have this clues, but failed to make a complete solution. Could You please give me a complete solution ?

Assume that $f_n∈M_ε$ and $f_n→f$.

Here it is uniform convergence so that f is continuous and convex.

If $F_n$ is extension of $f_n$ on [−ε,1+ε], then there is subsequence $F_n $s.t. $F_n(−ε)→a,F_n(1+ε)→b.$
Define F to be extension of f s.t. F(−ε)=a, F(1+ε)=b and F|[−ε,0], F|[1,1+ε] are linear functions.

Here $G_n(x)=sup_xF(x)$,$F_n(x)$ is convex and note that $G_n→F$. Hence F is convex. Let the set $M_ϵ$ is relatively compact, by the Arzela-Ascoli theorem. Now we can apply it here because, if $f∈M_ϵ$ :

- If x∈[0,1], then $|f(x)|=|f(x)−f(0)|≤M/2|x−0|≤M/2$ ;
- If $x_1,x_2∈[0,1]$, if ϵ>0  and if we take $δ=(2ϵ)/M$,

Then: 
 |x−y|<δ
⇒|f(x)−g(x)|<ϵ.

Then set $M_ϵ $is also closed. Therefore, it is closed.

Comment: Kindly format the text so that it will be readable, lest nobody will read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g$ be a function satisfying (1) and (2).
Since $g$ is convex, it is locally Lipschitz continuous. In particular, its Lipschitz constant in $[0,1]$ can be estimated by
$$
L := \max\{ |g(-\epsilon) - g(0)|/\epsilon, |g(1+\epsilon) - g(1)|/\epsilon\}.
$$
On the other hand
$$
|g(-\epsilon) - g(0)| = |g(-\epsilon) - f(0)|
\leq 2
$$
and, similarly, $|g(1+\epsilon) - g(1)|\leq 2$.

Hence every $f\in M_\epsilon$ is Lipschitz continuous with $Lip(f) \leq 2/\epsilon$, and $|f|\leq 1$, so that the set $M_\epsilon$ is equibounded and equicontinuous.

(The fact that $M_\epsilon$ is closed is immediate.)

Comment: Should I add something more with this ?

Comment: Maybe one could recall that the first part follows from the so-called three chords lemma for convex functions.

Comment: How to prove the boundedness ?

Comment: Since $\|f\|_\infty\leq 1$ for every $f\in M_\epsilon$, you have that $M_\epsilon$ is contained in the closed unit ball of $C([0,1])$.